# How to setup mouse in ubuntu for cs go?

Tags: mouse

I have a razer deathadder elite which I want to setup as close to my windows sensitivity as possible.

1. I want mouse acceleration turned off, and to remain off after reboots
2. I want to change the dpi of my mouse to 400
3. I want my sensitivity to be the same as the windows pointer speed, ie the 6th notch across
4. I want all mouse precision and snapping turned off

Is this going to be possible? Running latest ubuntu LTS.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it:

1. For latest Ubuntu LTS 18.04 you can download GNOME Tweaks from the Ubuntu Software Centre and mouse acceleration is included and can be switched off.
2. Downloaded openrazer drivers and installed polychromatic, changed dpi to 400
3. I found that CS Go takes raw mouse input so desktop sensitivity makes no difference, I did find that a sensitivity of half way is very similar to Windows 6th notch, measure distance mouse travels from one side of screen to other in both OSes to check.
4. Not much I could find on this but I am pretty sure none exist since the game uses raw input.